# html 5 canvas LineTo() line color issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing five horizontal lines to an HMTL 5 2D canvas:

```
var canvas_ctx = my_canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas_ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
    canvas_ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

    {
        let line_x = 0;
        let line_length = canvas_ctx.width;
        let offset = 5;
        let numLines = 5;
        let numYincrement = 10;
        for (let i=0;i<numLines * numYincrement;i+=numYincrement) {
            //canvas_ctx.beginPath();
            canvas_ctx.moveTo(line_x,i + offset);
            canvas_ctx.lineTo(line_length,i + offset);
            canvas_ctx.stroke();
            //canvas_ctx.closePath();
        }
    }
```

This should, ideally result in 5 black lines. Instead, the color of the lines seems to fade with each new line (as if it's a gradient!), so that line 5 is gray. If I uncomment `canvas_ctx.beginPath();` and `canvas_ctx.closePath();`, all lines become gray. Why is this happening??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Strokes do overlap from both sides of the coordinates.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
// draw big
ctx.scale(30, 30);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(5, 0);
ctx.lineTo(5, 10);
ctx.stroke();

drawPixelGrid();


function drawPixelGrid() {
  // simply renders where the pixel bounds are
  ctx.beginPath();
  // remove the zoom
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2; // avoid the problem we are demonstrating by using a perfect lineWidth ;-)

  for(let y=0; y<=300; y+=30) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(300, y);
    for(let x=0; x<=300; x+=30) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, 300);
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height=300></canvas>
```

But obviously, a pixel can't be set to two colors at the same time. So browsers apply [*antialiasing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing), which will fade your pixel color to an other color, being the result of mixing the background and the foreground color.
So for a black stroke over a white or transparent background, this leads to actual gray pixels being rendered. Here I'll keep using red as an example:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
// first draw as on a 10*10 canvas
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(5, 0);
ctx.lineTo(5, 10);
ctx.stroke();

// zoom it
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = 0;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
ctx.drawImage(c, 0,0,9000,9000);

drawPixelGrid();

// this is not red...

function drawPixelGrid() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;

  for(let y=0; y<=300; y+=30) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(300, y);
    for(let x=0; x<=300; x+=30) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, 300);
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height=300></canvas>
```

One way to avoid it is generally to apply an offset on your coordinates so that the line extends correctly on pixels boundaries. E.g for a 1px lineWidth, you would apply a 0.5 offset:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle="red";
// first draw as on a 10*10 canvas
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(5.5, 0); // offset +0.5px
ctx.lineTo(5.5, 10);
ctx.stroke();

// zoom it
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = 0;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
ctx.drawImage(c, 0,0,9000,9000);

drawPixelGrid();
// now we've got a real red

function drawPixelGrid() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'gray';
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;

  for(let y=0; y<=300; y+=30) {
    ctx.moveTo(0, y);
    ctx.lineTo(300, y);
    for(let x=0; x<=300; x+=30) {
      ctx.moveTo(x, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(x, 300);
    }
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" height=300></canvas>
```

But in your case, you are drawing at 0.5px lineWidth, so no offset will be able to get rid of this antialiasing.

So if you want perfect color, choose a correct lineWidth.