# Canvas position in grid inaccurate

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

The x and y position of the grid on the canvas is being put 1 row to the left and 1 column above on some cells. I don't know what's causing this but it mostly happens in the middle to nearing the end of the grid.

```js
'use strict';

// the canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

class Node {
  constructor(row, col) {
    // save current index (row, col) to know where in the canvas it is
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;

    this.show = color => {
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(this.row * cellDimension, this.col * cellDimension, cellDimension - 1, cellDimension - 1);
      context.fillStyle = color;
      context.fill();
    }
  }
}

// the counter from input field
const colRowCount = 60;
// will be determined from setup
let cellDimension;

let gridArray = new Array(colRowCount);
//start and finish
let startNode = new Node();
let endNode = new Node();
// array of the path nodes
let totalPath = new Array();


// setup all the neccessities
const setup = () => {
  // subtract the height of menu
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  cellDimension = canvas.width / colRowCount;

  for (let i = 0; i < colRowCount; i++) {
    gridArray[i] = new Array(colRowCount);
    for (let j = 0; j < colRowCount; j++) {
      gridArray[i][j] = new Node(i, j);
    }
  }

  context.beginPath();
  for (let i = 0; i < canvas.width; i += cellDimension) {
    // horizontal divider
    context.moveTo(0, i);
    context.lineTo(canvas.width, i);

    // vertical divider
    context.moveTo(i, 0);
    context.lineTo(i, canvas.width);

    context.strokeStyle = '#ddd';
    context.stroke();
  }
}

const getMousePosition = event => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  // top left
  let cellX = 0;
  let cellY = 0;
  // bounds of the square unit
  const bounds = Math.floor(Math.floor(canvas.width) / colRowCount);

  for (let i = 1; i < colRowCount; i++) {
    if (x > (bounds * i)) {
      cellX = i;
    }

    if (y > (bounds * i)) {
      cellY = i;
    }
  }

  return {
    x: cellX,
    y: cellY
  };
}

const placeStart = position => {
  startNode = gridArray[position.x][position.y];
  startNode.show('green');
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // setup the canvas
  setup();
  // event listener for canvas
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    placeStart(getMousePosition(event));
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
}


/*for all the grids with canvas*/

.canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
}


/*for all the grids with canvas*/
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <canvas class='canvas'>
    </canvas>
</div>
```

The one in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfm3qnch/1/) is behaving much more unexpectedly.

Comment: There is nothing to say that cellDimension is naturally an integer. Also when you floor things you lose accuracy (downwards). Are these causing the problem?

Comment: @AHaworth, I added after I noticed the problem so it's not the floor. But I do agree its gonna cause some more inaccuracy. I'll remove them on my local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple issues here...

First, the canvas has two sizes, the one of its buffer, set by its `width` and `height` attributes, and its rendering one (ruled by CSS).
Here both sizes are different, so the actual canvas image is being stretched by the CSS renderer, causing antialiasing and rounding imprecisions. [See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Then, `stroke()` does overlap on both sides of the provided coordinates, so with a `lineWidth` of `1`, you need to add (or remove) a 0.5px offset so that a vertical or horizontal line fits correctly in the boundaries of a single pixel, otherwise once again you'll have antialising kick in. [See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733682/html-5-canvas-lineto-line-color-issues/49734715#49734715)

Finally, your coordinates are not even rounded, so you will fall in between two pixel coordinates, once more adding antialiasing...

Here is an attempt to fix all that:

```js
'use strict';

// the canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
class Node {
  constructor(row, col) {
    // save current index (row, col) to know where in the canvas it is
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;

    this.show = color => {
      const border_offset = context.lineWidth;
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(this.row * cellDimension + border_offset, this.col * cellDimension + border_offset, cellDimension - border_offset, cellDimension - border_offset);
      context.fillStyle = color;
      context.fill();
      // remember we're on, so we can be redrawn on resize
      this.color = color;
    }
  }
}

// The counter from input field
const colRowCount = 60;
// Will be determined from setup
let cellDimension;

let gridArray = new Array(colRowCount);
//start and finish
let startNode = new Node();
let endNode = new Node();
// array of the path nodes
let totalPath = new Array();
// Initialize all the nodes directly, 
// we don't need to know the size of the cells
// or of the canvas to do so.
for (let i = 0; i < colRowCount; i++) {
  gridArray[i] = new Array(colRowCount);
  for (let j = 0; j < colRowCount; j++) {
    gridArray[i][j] = new Node(i, j);
  }
}

// called at init, and at every page resize
const redraw = () => {
  // get the size of the container measured by CSS
  const parent = canvas.parentNode;
  const parent_width = parent.offsetWidth;
  // remove 1 lineWidth for outer strokes
  const max_grid_size = parent_width - context.lineWidth;
  // cellDimension must be an integer
  cellDimension = Math.floor( max_grid_size / colRowCount );
  const grid_size = cellDimension * colRowCount;
  // now we know the size of our grid,
  // our canvas will be one lineWidth bigger to show the outer strokes
  canvas.width = canvas.height = grid_size + context.lineWidth;

  context.beginPath();
  const stroke_offset = context.lineWidth / 2;
  for (let i = 0; i <= grid_size; i += cellDimension) {
    // horizontal divider
    context.moveTo(stroke_offset, i + stroke_offset);
    context.lineTo(grid_size + stroke_offset, i + stroke_offset);

    // vertical divider
    context.moveTo(i + stroke_offset, stroke_offset);
    context.lineTo(i + stroke_offset, grid_size + stroke_offset );
  }
  // stroke only once
  context.strokeStyle = '#ddd';
  context.stroke();
  
  // redraw all the nodes that were already active
  gridArray.flat().filter( (node) => node.color )
    .forEach( (node) => node.show( node.color ) );
}

const getMousePosition = event => {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  const y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  // top left
  let cellX = 0;
  let cellY = 0;
  // bounds of the square unit
  const bounds = Math.floor(Math.floor(canvas.width) / colRowCount);

  for (let i = 1; i < colRowCount; i++) {
    if (x > (bounds * i)) {
      cellX = i;
    }

    if (y > (bounds * i)) {
      cellY = i;
    }
  }

  return {
    x: cellX,
    y: cellY
  };
}

const placeStart = position => {
  startNode = gridArray[position.x][position.y];
  startNode.show('green');
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  redraw();
  // event listener for canvas
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    placeStart(getMousePosition(event));
  });
  window.onresize = redraw;
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 100%;
}

.canvas {
  border: 1px solid green;
  /* we let the canvas buffer's size rule its presentation dimensions */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <canvas class='canvas'></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I added your function to my code. I made an additional function to setup a grid, because I added a colCount which would depend on the height of the canvas. It's not drawing anything on the canvas somehow. May you take a look? Here is the [repo](https://github.com/pdarceno/pathfinding/blob/master/js/setup.js)

Comment: Btw, I added your parent_height to the constants [here](https://github.com/pdarceno/pathfinding/blob/master/js/constants.js)

Comment: parent_height should be recalculated at every resize event. Don't reinitialize the Nodes at each resize, you'll loose which were clicked on. `window.onresize = setup();` will set the return value of `setup()` (`undefined`) as the resize handler, I wrote `window.onresize = setup`.  Not sure that's everything, I don't have much time to review your code sorry.

Comment: That's fine. I got it working, thanks very much I appreciate it