# HTML Canvas multiple identical strokes makes the stroke brighter?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a black html body background and a transparent canvas that I am stroking a single white line onto.
Every time I stroke the line in code, the line appears brighter despite using full opacity in the stroke settings.

```
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"; // Non transparent white.
context.lineWidth = 1; //Single pixel line width
context.setLineDash([]); //No line dash
```

I can see it getting visibly brighter white with every stroke, up to 4 strokes.

```
context.stroke();
context.stroke();
context.stroke();
context.stroke();
```

Why is this happening? Surely the canvas data being drawn to is exactly the same, and the stroke should remain identical no matter how many times I call it?

I tried stroking up to 16 times, but can only visibly tell it getting brighter up to 4, but with a single stroke its easy to see that its not a completely solid white line, If I press my face against the screen I can see the white dots with very slight black between them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [html 5 canvas LineTo() line color issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49733682/html-5-canvas-lineto-line-color-issues)

Comment: Yes I think it does. Fixing everything with a 0.5px offset.